# Rinsing vs not rinsing until 30 mins after brushing teeth (dry sensation)

Tags: dentistry, toothpaste, toothbrush

First timer here.. I don't know this situation has been asked/shared before or not, but I couldn't find any similar question online.

So I have read the recommendation that better we do not rinse after brushing teeth and just let the toothpaste do its work for 30 minutes before rinsing/eating/anything.

I have been doing that. I make sure to also spit excess toothpaste. However, I always feel this dry sensation in my mouth. Why? Because I also read that, in addition, it is not recommended to swallow/ingest the toothpaste..

So for more or less 30 minutes, my mouth does nothing..not even swallowing saliva because I know I will swallow the toothpaste. And when the duration ends, I suffer from this dry sensation..and just go on to quickly rinse by water and hope the suffering ends. This of course keep repeating twice everyday.

If it is only 15 minutes, I think I am fine..but yes, I am such a strict person following scientific-looking recommendation strictly. So if it is recommended for maximum benefit that:

1. Don't rinse for around 30 minutes, just spit out excess toothpaste after brushing.
2. Don't swallow toothpaste.

Then I do just that..and that dry sensation inside my mouth is unavoidable.

Is there any solution to this?

Thank you very much for the help and suggestions! Really appreciate it!

EDIT: Some sources (but the thing is I also don't know the reliability):

On not rinsing?

1. [NHS.uk](https://www.nhs.uk/live-well/healthy-body/how-to-keep-your-teeth-clean/)
2. [Oral Health Foundation](https://www.dentalhealth.org/news/spit-dont-rinse-for-better-oral-health)

On not swallowing (in large amount of course)?

1. [Clubb Dental](https://www.clubbdental.com.au/why-you-shouldnt-swallow-your-toothpaste.html)
2. [Healthline](https://www.healthline.com/health/fluoride-toothpaste#safety-for-young-children)

Nevertheless, my main thing is not mainly about criticizing each source, but about asking the better advice here. Thank you.

Comment: Can you link to few sources you find them reliable and they say what you say? Then we can discuss about that.

Comment: @Jan Sorry, I think that is part of my problem too. I do not know which is reliable or not. I am just surfing through internet..and in google/youtube I found many suggesting not rinsing, although most I think do not give some estimates on when I can start rinsing. Some estimate 30 minutes until eating, but I just want to rinse, not drink or eat to erase this dry feeling. Hence, I come here to hopefully learn from more reliable experts and ask for better suggestion regardless of sources I visited.

Comment: OK, no problem.

Comment: I've never heard such advice. Can you give us an example of a credible source making that recommendation?

Comment: @Jan I have edited to include some sources.

Comment: @CareyGregory I have added them in edit..with emphasize in the last sentences.

Comment: Related: https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/1401/7951

Comment: @10understanding as Chris Rogers pointed out, your question appears to be a duplicate of another question that was already asked and answered, so I've closed it as a duplicate. But welcome to MedSci and thank you for editing the question and adding the supporting references. That's how you make a good question.

Comment: @CareyGregory Thanks. However, although indeed it is related, I do not think it is the exact duplicate, as I have stated the condition and question clearly (since the answer in that thread is pretty much what I read in the entire internet I surf). My question is more about the solution to drying sensation in mouth after around 30 minutes of not rinsing/drinking/eating..and about swallowing too. The "when" and the "how" are not answered in the accepted answer of that thread. I apply for reopening this question. Thanks...

Comment: @ChrisRogers Thanks. However, there is a noticeable difference of focus in the question.

Comment: Related titles do not equal similar context and details.

Comment: Okay, what do you think your question asks that the other one doesn't answer? I'm perfectly willing to reopen your question but I don't see what's missing.

Comment: @CareyGregory Thank you very much. Once again, I would like to know better advice/better solution on the dry sensation when I try not to rinse and not to swallow the toothpaste for 30 minutes. This is not in the related thread. As mentioned, I am thinking that: Maybe just not rinsing for 15 minutes is OK, but will the toothpaste still be effective? This also leads to the discussion: How long exactly do I need to wait before rinsing? None of these is in that thread. Or, using your term, these are missing still.

Comment: @CareyGregory I will mention again: This dry sensation does not exist for the whole day for me. I believe it only exists because I do not swallow anything (including saliva) for 30 minutes to avoid swallowing toothpaste after the toothbrushing. What I found in that thread is just repeating what I found in the links I have added in the edits, which of course is not the main concern of this thread.

Comment: How to avoid a dry mouth sensation is personal medical advice, which is off topic here. Whether you should wait to rinse is the only aspect of your question that's on topic.

Comment: @CareyGregory I see. Thanks. User named Jan above in fact has answered the seemingly off-topic question in the related post tho. Thanks a lot.